# Multiple logins with JMeter: an admin and an employee

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Here is a scenario I am trying to automate.

I want to log in into my application as admin, and admin will register two activities for employee and Employee will log in into his profile and will complete two activity which has created by admin and then employee will logout. How can we perform this kind of a test using JMeter?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve this form of synchronisation using [Inter-Thread Communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) plugin. This way you will be able to block the `employee` thread until the activities will be created so the employee could complete them.

See [SynchronisationPluginsExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx) Test Plan for reference on how to make one thread to wait for another thread completion.

You can install Inter-Thread Communication Plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager).

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Inter Thread Communication]